# Multipart JSON POST request

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

please read my post:

I need to post the image to the JSON WS with this parameters:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
Content-Length: {number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body} -- Check your rest client                   API's. Some would automatically determine content-length at runtime. Eg. jersey client api.
 --foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json;
{
"filename": "cloudx.jpg"
}
--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg
{JPEG data}
--foo_bar_baz--
```

I'm building Android application and I need to write the request to send the image to the above WS. I was looking around for some time and I didn't found good resource to study this issue I have.

Comment: Apache http client should have multipart support.

Comment: I agree, but I still dont know how to create a request with these 3 headers.. I will really need a code on this one, I think.. Tnx..

Comment: Google is your friend. `java multipart request`

Answer (score 1):

following may give you basic idea

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(<URI>);
HttpEntity entity = new FileEntity(file,ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
//there are other types of entities and content types too check documentation
req.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(req);
```